# ggvis in jupyter/ipython notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, ggvis, jupyter

It is possible to use `rmagic` to use R for plotting in an ipython notebook.

#### Example Usage

```
%%R 
ggplot() + geom_point(data=ChickWeight, aes(Time, weight))
```

The next evolution of `ggplot2` is `ggvis`, which has support for interactive graphics. So I naively tried to run ggvis code in the notebook.

#### Code

```
%%R 
library(ggvis) 
library(dplyr) 
ChickWeight %>% ggvis(~Time, ~weight) %>% layer_points()
```

#### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-d92c06ea4af8> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic(u'R', u'', u'# ChickWeight %>% head\nChickWeight %>% ggvis(~Time, ~weight) %>% layer_points()')

/opt/virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2259             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2260             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2261                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2262             return result
   2263 

/opt/virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.pyc in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/opt/virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/opt/virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.pyc in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
    640                     old_writeconsole = ri.get_writeconsole()
    641                     ri.set_writeconsole(self.write_console)
--> 642                     ro.r.show(result)
    643                     text_output += self.flush()
    644                     ri.set_writeconsole(old_writeconsole)

/opt/virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    168                 v = kwargs.pop(k)
    169                 kwargs[r_k] = v
--> 170         return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    171 
    172 pattern_link = re.compile(r'\\link\{(.+?)\}')

/opt/virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     98         for k, v in kwargs.items():
     99             new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2ri(v)
--> 100         res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
    101         res = conversion.ri2ro(res)
    102         return res

RRuntimeError: Error in view_static(x, ...) : unused argument (useS4 = FALSE)
```

This code works fine in Rstudio.

Is it possible to run ggvis in an ipython notebook (or anything shiny for that matter, I think that that's the problem)?

Comment: ggvis is probably doing R console-specific dark magic. The best is to open an issue on the rpy2 issue tracker on bitbucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, you'll have to either call R's print method explicitly or customize rpy2's conversion rules for ipython (not shown here).

```
%%R 
library(ggvis) 
library(dplyr) 
p <- ChickWeight %>% ggvis(~Time, ~weight) %>% layer_points() 
print(p)
```

Note that the figure obtained is in a *different* page than your ipython notebook, which breaks a bit the idea that notebooks are self-contained.

Comment: is there no known way around this or is it theoretically even impossible to get around this?

Comment: A way around this can be to use rpy2's conversion system to return an object that ipython will understand as being a figure (see http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/FRidh/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb).

Comment: Is saving to `p` necessary? Can you just pipe to `print` at the end `... %>% print` instead?